# When to use HC1 vs HC2 errors in estimating heteroskedasticity robust standard errors?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Suppose I have data $Y$ regressed against $X$, where $Y$ is the level of health for an individual (from 1 to 10), and $X$ is the whether or no the individual is above 50 years of age. If I wanted to estimate the difference in mean level of health in individuals above or equal to 50, and under 50 — and wanted standard errors, should I use

1. Regular OLS standard errors
2. HC1 errors
3. HC2 errors

?

Thanks

Comment: How many observations do you have?

Comment: @dimitriy I have around 3000 observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bounded outcome like that and a linear regression model, you will have heteroskedastic errors. The logic is similar to why you get heteroskedasticity with a linear probability model (LPM). That knocks out (1).

There is [no theorem with a guarantee (yet)](https://twitter.com/jmwooldridge/status/1449778751911305219), but with $\frac{k}{n}$ small, HC1 SEs tend to be smaller than HC2. Here $k=2$ and $n=3,000$ which favors HC1. But I suspect that the choice may not matter too much with this sample size and number of covariates.

You can always do a simulation to confirm.

Comment: LPM being a linear probability model?

Comment: @Dave Yes and edited.

Comment: What is the connection between the bounded outcome and hetereoskedastic errors?

Comment: @user321627 Suppose $y=8$ on an 1-10 scale. If there is a positive error, it can only be +2 at the most but down to -7 in the other direction. These limits depend on the value of y, so the error variance cannot be constant.

Comment: @dimitriy Thank you for this, what confuses me is that I had always assumed hetereoskedasticity meant $Var(\epsilon_i)$ was some function of $x_i$. But here, is the fact $Var(\epsilon_i)$ is a function of $y_i$ also imply hetereoskedasticity? In other words, a function of $y$ vs. a function of $x$?

Comment: @user321627 It can be a function of x, but does not have to be. There are many ways to be unconstant. It can be a function of some omitted z, uncorrelated with x. You can also have a homoskedastic DGP (say a standard ordered probit with homoskedastic normal errors), but using OLS induces misspecification and heteroskedastic errors. But you can think of it as a function of both y and x here since the residual at y=k will depend on whether x=0 or x=1. In fact, in this simple model, each value of y will have 2 distinct residuals.